# vb.Net: How can I read a large XML file quickly?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read [this](http://wiitdb.com/wiitdb.zip?LANG=EN) XML document.

An excerpt:

```
<datafile xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="wiitdb.xsd"> 
    <WiiTDB version="20100217113738" games="2368"/>     
        <game name="Help Wanted: 50 Wacky Jobs (DEMO) (USA) (EN)"> 
            <id>DHKE18</id> 
            <type/> 
            <region>NTSC-U</region> 
            <languages>EN</languages> 
            <locale lang="EN"> 
                <title>Help Wanted: 50 Wacky Jobs (DEMO)</title> 
                <synopsis/> 
            </locale> 
            <developer>HUDSON SOFT CO., LTD.</developer> 
            <publisher>Hudson Entertainment, Inc.</publisher> 
            <date year="2009" month="" day=""/> 
            <genre>party</genre> 
            <rating type="ESRB" value="E10+"> 
                <descriptor>comic mischief</descriptor> 
                <descriptor>mild cartoon violence</descriptor> 
                <descriptor>mild suggestive themes</descriptor> 
            </rating> 
            <wi-fi players="0"/> 
            <input players="2"> 
                <control type="wiimote" required="true"/> 
                <control type="nunchuk" required="true"/> 
            </input> 
            <rom version="" name="Help Wanted: 50 Wacky Jobs (DEMO) (USA) (EN).iso" size="4699979776"/> 
        </game>
```

So far I have this:

```
    Dim doc as XPathDocument
    Dim nav as XPathNavigator
    Dim iter as XPathNodeIterator
    Dim lstNav As XPathNavigator
    Dim iterNews As XPathNodeIterator

    doc = New XPathDocument("wiitdb.xml")
        nav = doc.CreateNavigator
        iter = nav.Select("/WiiTDB/game") 'Your node name goes here
        'Loop through the records in that node
        While iter.MoveNext
            'Get the data we need from the node
            lstNav = iter.Current
            iterNews = lstNav.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Element, False)
            'Loop through the child nodes
            txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & vbNewLine & iterNews.Current.Name & ": " & iterNews.Current.Value
        End While
```

It just skips the "While iter.MoveNext" part of the code. I tries it with a simple XML file, and it works fine.

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you using? 2.0? or 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

I think your XPath query is off. WiiTDB is a closed node, so you need to look for /datafile/game or //game.

Comment: how did you determine that?...might I ask.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but it just goes on forever and crashes. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Or make it take less time?

Comment: Saif - the formatting is a bit misleading. Nodes are usually <a></a>, or they can be self-closing like <a />. The datafile node is not closed, and the WiiTDB is closed. Therefore, the game node is in the datafile node, so you use XPath to do /datafile/game. //game will find all <game> nodes.

Comment: MI - unfortunately, I think XPathDocument is going to be the least memory intensive way without using LINQ to XML (or another in-line parsing). Is the crash happening when you load the first XPathDocument, or later on in the process? You may be able to get away with not doing an inner loop, and just using XPath to query the information directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace instead: create a dedicated, serializable class to hold the data you wish to load and define shared serialize / deserialize functions with strongly typed arguments to do the work for you.

As the structure of the new classes will closely follow that of your XML data, there should be no confusion as to which data is located where within a run time instance.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683241/read-xml-file-vb-net/11694606#11694606) for an idea of how to create a class from an example XML file.